# Is there any way to shorten this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any alternative to shorted this code? It's working fine, but I'm thinking if there is any way to shorted it.

```js
function hideElem() {
  $("._nf-short-ans").on("click", function() {
    $(".nf-short-desc").removeClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-main-c").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-btn-opt").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-para").addClass("nf-hide");
  });

  $("._nf-para").on("click", function() {
    $(".nf-para").removeClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-main-c").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-btn-opt").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-short-desc").addClass("nf-hide");
  });

  $("._nf-multi-choice").on("click", function() {
    $(".nf-para").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-main-c").removeClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-btn-opt").removeClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-short-desc").addClass("nf-hide");
  });

  $("._nf-checkbox").on("click", function() {
    $(".nf-para").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-main-c").removeClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-btn-opt").removeClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-short-desc").addClass("nf-hide");
  });
}
```

Comment: There most likely is, but to give you the most accurate answer we would need to see the associated HTML and CSS

Comment: The last 2 blocks do the same thing, you can start by grouping them in the same css selector ? `$("._nf-checkboxm, ._nf-multi-choice")`

Comment: Hi All Thanks for answering :) I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

First, you only need one handler if you use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Furthermore, you can use multiple selectors in JQuery. Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.classList.contains("_nf-short-ans") {
   $(".nf-short-desc").removeClass("nf-hide"),
   return  $(".nf-main-c, .nf-btn-opt, .nf-para")
    .addClass("nf-hide");
  }
  if (origin.classList.contains("._nf-para") {
    $(".nf-para").removeClass("nf-hide");
    return $(".nf-main-c, .nf-btn-opt, .nf-short-desc")
      .addClass("nf-hide");
  }
  /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: You made a typo in the line that says `.removeClass("nf-hide"),`.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: The handle function will be executed for every click in the document... it's ok until you make some nasty loops in the handle function I guess

Answer (score 0):

Here we go my modest proposal, you can try it. the toggleClass part can be tricky thought.

```
function hideElem() {  
  $("._nf-short-ans, ._nf-para").on("click", function() {
    $(".nf-btn-opt, .nf-main-c").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-para, .nf-short-desc").toggleClass("nf-hide");
  });

  $("._nf-multi-choice, ._nf-checkbox").on("click", function() {
    $(".nf-para, .nf-short-desc").addClass("nf-hide");
    $(".nf-main-c, .nf-btn-opt").removeClass("nf-hide");
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch()` try this snippet:

```js
function hide(n){
  switch(n){
    case 1:
        $(".nf-short-desc").removeClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-main-c").addClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-btn-opt").addClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-para").addClass("nf-hide");
        break
    case 2: 
        $(".nf-para").removeClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-main-c").addClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-btn-opt").addClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-short-desc").addClass("nf-hide");
        break
    case 3:
        $(".nf-para").addClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-main-c").removeClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-btn-opt").removeClass("nf-hide");
        $(".nf-short-desc").addClass("nf-hide");
        break
  }
}
```

```css
.nf-hide{opacity:0;}
div{border:1px solid black; width:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="hide(1)">case 1</button>  
<button onclick="hide(2)">case 2</button>  
<button onclick="hide(3)">case 3</button>  
<p>
<div class="nf-short-desc nf-hide">short</div>
<div class="nf-main-c nf-hide">main</div>
<div class="nf-btn-opt nf-hide">btn</div>
<div class="nf-para nf-hide">para</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the class name are still the same for every block.
I suggest, instead use "_nf-short-ans", "_nf-multi-choice", etc. to use one name class for every anchor,
eg:

```
<a href="#" class="_nf-short-ans _nf-click">text</a>
<a href="#" class="_nf-multi-choice _nf-click">text</a>
```

Then you can use _nf-click in your js for detecting the event

```
$("._nf-click").on("click", function() {
       $(this).find(".nf-para").addClass("nf-hide");
       $(this).find(".nf-main-c").removeClass("nf-hide");
       $(this).find(".nf-btn-opt").removeClass("nf-hide");
       $(this).find(".nf-short-desc").addClass("nf-hide");
  });
```

this is just an idea, because without your HTML code is not really easy to understand if this code can work